# Tense Inconsistency/Shifting?

Tags: tenses

Kind of new to this, so I hope I'm posting this appropriately.

I was recently given a bulk of text that was translated to English, supposedly intended for publication in some capacity.

While my task didn't involve the linguistics, I was nonetheless puzzled by the fact that the contents, detailed by the writer from his perspective (and apparently translated quite literally), are always in the present tense, including when describing past events (to the point where in some cases it becomes nearly impossible to tell if he's referring to past or present things).

My question is this: in the following sample...

> That first week in July 1992 is a time for decisions, and by its end, I make a personal decision to do whatever I can to get assigned to the team. It is a commitment with a goal, but with no guarantee of success.... In my opinion, such decisions serve as many-sided contracts of sorts: between the decision-maker and himself, and between the decision-maker and the other participants - and priorities determine our decision-making processes.... It is clear to me that this is a really difficult challenge, but at this stage I'm deciding to go for it regardless.

...shouldn't the first two lines and the last line at the end essentially be shifted to the past tense?

> That first week in July 1992 ***was*** a time for decisions, and by its end, I ***made*** a personal decision to do whatever I ***could*** to get assigned to the team. It ***was*** a commitment with a goal, but with no guarantee of success... In my opinion, such decisions serve as many-sided contracts of sorts: between the decision-maker and himself, and between the decision-maker and the other participants - and priorities determine our decision-making processes... It ***was*** clear to me that day that this ***was*** a really difficult challenge, but at ***that*** stage, I ***decided*** to go for it regardless.

Or is the original sample grammatically correct, and this is merely an issue of a style that just seems unusual to me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a literary style (I don't off-hand know the name) that involves writing most everything in present tense.  It's vaguely possible that the original non-English text was written in this style and a decision was made to maintain it.  But I suspect that there are also languages where present tense is used for certain constructs which should normally be expressed as past-tense in English.  (I'm no foreign language expert, but if you identified the source language it might help others here determine what language "quirks" might be at work.)

Comment: @HotLicks Are you thikning of the "Historical Present", by chance?

Comment: @DanBron - Sounds good.

Comment: It doesn't sound like it from your question (as you seem to be asking this from a hypothetical point of view) but I would strongly suggest you don't make any changes (particularly as this is not what you were hired for) without talking to whoever is in control of this. It is completely possible that this is intentional, so editing the copy may be detrimental to your actual work. There was actually a very related question on  [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70684/is-it-the-graphic-designers-job-to-correct-suggest-grammar-and-punctuation) about this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as if the author is presenting her narrative in the form of (or actually drawing it from) a ***journal*** of what she thought and what decisions and actions she took at specific points along the way.

If she maintains this style throughout the work, or employs it at otherwise 'marked' points, and it's reasonably coherent, I wouldn't change her "radical of presentation" (the phrase is Northrup Frye's) unless there is some overriding external reason  to do so (such as the publisher of the work demanding it).

Answer (score 0):

As Hotlicks suggested and Dan confirmed, this linguistic device is the "historical present".

> The present tense used instead of the past in vivid narrative,
>   especially in titles, such as ‘The Empire Strikes Back’, and
>   informally in speech, e.g. ‘so I say to him’.
>   [Reference: Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/historic-present)

So the simple answer to your question is yes, grammatically it's fine. 
The broader question as to whether or not it's correct to use this device boils down to what is the intent of the author?

If the purpose of the text is readability and straight forward comprehension (the author is relating facts) then I would certainly say that the past tense would be the best option. Why? Because it is simply easier to comprehend the concrete meaning of what is being conveyed, i.e.

> There was some past event, these are the facts, these are my thoughts
>   on the matter.

Which is essentially the three fold structure the passage you quoted takes. 
However if the author is more concerned with impact on their audience, perhaps trying to evoke some kind of emotional response, then the use of the historical present would certainly be a good choice.

Take this example for instance: -

> If the funeral had been yesterday, I could not recollect it better.
>   The very air of the best parlour, when I went in at the door, the
>   bright condition of the fire, the shining of the wine in the
>   decanters, the patterns of the glasses and plates, the faint sweet
>   smell of cake, the odour of Miss Murdstone dress, and your black
>   clothes. Mr. Chillip is in the room, and comes to speak to me. "And
>   how is Master David?" he says, kindly." - [Dickens, David Copperfield, Chapter 9](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=w1VXb1qce0IC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=If%20the%20funeral%20had%20been%20yesterday,%20I%20could%20not%20recollect%20it%20better.%20The%20very%20air%20of%20the%20best%20parlour,%20when%20I%20went%20in%20at%20the%20door,%20the%20bright%20condition%20of%20the%20fire,%20the%20shining%20of%20the%20wine%20in%20the%20decanters,%20the%20patterns%20of%20the%20glasses%20and%20plates,%20the%20faint%20sweet%20smell%20of%20cake,%20the%20odour%20of%20Miss%20Murdstone%20dress,%20and%20your%20black%20clothes.%20Mr.%20Chillip%20is%20in%20the%20room,%20and%20comes%20to%20speak%20to%20me.%20%22And%20how%20is%20Master%20David?%22%20he%20says,%20kindly.&source=bl&ots=NqMkeSG69O&sig=8kYC7S9KiV1f7GrY8XD96T05wnc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4xo6C5ZTOAhVqKMAKHfQSDV8Q6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=If%20the%20funeral%20had%20been%20yesterday%2C%20I%20could%20not%20recollect%20it%20better.%20The%20very%20air%20of%20the%20best%20parlour%2C%20when%20I%20went%20in%20at%20the%20door%2C%20the%20bright%20condition%20of%20the%20fire%2C%20&f=false)

Notice how a real sense of immediacy is created here, we are reliving this moment with the narrative voice. It's a very different effect to if the passage was simply written in the past tense. We are more likely to feel empathy with the narrative voice as a result, it creates a more immersive reading experience.

So the question really comes down to what is your authorial intent? Are you writing for comprehsion or poetic effect.

Comment: The purpose of the text is primarily readability - the main structure of most of the paragraphs seems to be "past event being described/author's general opinion on said event being described/past event is continued. It's generally written for comprehension.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like they have just confused their tenses in translation. So for comprehension I would say the translation would be better suited written in the past tense. It's a mistake that can be made by a non native speaker in translation but from the literary perspective there is nothing 'wrong' with the text per se. For instance I enjoyed reading it more than I would if it had been written in the past tense, I was interested in what was happening here, that's the power of the historical present!

Comment: As this is not the OPs text, and editing it is not part of their job, doing so is not appropriate without discussing it with the person who did the translation.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the OP edit the text. Simply that it should be re-translated if the intention is pure comprehension, as suggested.

Comment: @Gary: Actually, from what I've gathered, it's more like a case of preserving the original 100% - the translator kept the grammatical structure of the original source without taking into consideration how it might come off in English.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was actually very well written, so did second guess the idea that the translator had made an error. Usually when something is written that well, the translator is highly skilled, so wouldn't make a trivial mistake like that I would think.